# не работает функция moveBy() Javascript

Tags: javascript

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Открытие новых окон и запись содержания</title>
<script type="text/javascript">  
var win;
function winOpen() {
win = window.open('new.html', '', 'height=200, width=300, left=500, top=300');  
}
function winMove() {
if(win){
    win.focus();
    win.moveBy(50,50);      
}
function winClose() {
if(win)win.close();
}
 </script>
</head>
<body>
<p class="p1"><a href="javascript:winOpen();">Открыть окно</a></p>
<p class="p3"><a href="javascript:winMove();">Передвинуть окно</a></p>
<p class="p2"><a href="javascript:winClose();">Закрыть окно</a></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Вопрос: при запуске функции winMove() окно не двигается по монитору. Почему?

Comment: есть ошибки в консоли?

Comment: blocked a frame with origin "null" from accessing a cross-origin frame - эта ошибка была в консоли. Одним словом, через протокол file:// браузер блокирует работу, в частности, этой функции. Через протокол http:// все заработало на ура!

Comment: вот тут подробно все объясняется: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25098021/securityerror-blocked-a-frame-with-origin-from-accessing-a-cross-origin-frame